# How to create dynamic variables in Angularjs, javascript and other scripting language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, variables, dynamic-variables

I want to create dynamic variables like Vikas0, Vikas1, Vikas2, Vikas3 and so on.

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  $scope.servicesDataList[key].list="Vikas"+key;
  // will print Vikas0, Vikas1, Vikas2, Vikas3
  console.log($scope.servicesDataList[key].list); 
});
```

Now I want to create dynamic variables. Will any one knows how can I achieve this. I hope I am able to elaborate my question.

Comment: you cannot create an independent dynamic variable but can create a hash map instead as var hashValue and then use hashValue[$scope.servicesDataList[key].list] = "value"

Comment: Why not use an array?

Comment: I got a result in json, that's why not using array

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use.
 the syntax would be = $scope["vikas"+key] = []

    $.each(data, function(key, value){    
       $scope["Vikas"+key] = value;    
       console.log($scope["vikas"+key].value);
     will print Vikas0, Vikas1,Vikas2, Vikas3  

});
```

Comment: So it will create Vikas0 variable with the value Vikas0

Comment: and it can hold any value like array, JSON, string or any

Answer (score 0):

You can with using array of object act as a dynamic variable.

```
             Var conctVar="":
              $.each(data, function(key, value){
                conctVar= conctVar + "{Vikas"+key + ":Vikas"+value+"},";
               });

               conctVar=conctVar.slice(0,-1);
               $scope.FinalObject=JSON.parse(conctVar);// now the string will convert to a array object
```

Now you can get the array object looks like below

> $scope.FinalObject.Vikas1,// value is vikas1
>
> $scope.FinalObject.Vikas2,// value is vikas2
>
> $scope.FinalObject.Vikas3,//value is vikas3
>
> $scope.FinalObject.Vikas4//value is vikas4